# how does the script finds the value of n in function(n)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery. I saw a program online and found that the value of n in a function starts from 0 to as many number of that element. In the below example, the img element appears once and jQuery gets this element based on the index (which it gets from the variable n in function) and then performs the operation. Can you please explain how the value for n is defined and incremented.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("img").attr("width",function(n,v){
          return v-50;
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <img src="img_pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" width="284" height="213">
    <br>
    <button>Decrease image width by 50px</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr

Comment: @Satpal This isn't a question about jQuery documentation, it's a question about block arguments.

Comment: The answer is in the documentation for the library that he is using. a link to the documentation is appropriate. (unless of course you want to go into the source code to explain it)

Comment: this is a great example of why you should always use descriptive variable and parameter names. `function(index, width)`

Answer (score 0):

It's using a callback function, defined in jquery. The function signature is `function(index, attr)`

From the [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

> A function returning the value to set. this is the current element.
>   Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old
>   attribute value as arguments.

Your method:

```
$("img").attr("width",function(n,v){
          return v-50;
});
```

supposedly couldn't work, because `v` (the current attribute value) may be `undefined`. In that case it would return `NaN`.

Feel free to Play around with this [**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/tuhunuza/4/edit?js,output)

Comment: the current attribute value is "284", which when used next to `-50` will be converted to a number.

Comment: @KevinB I agree. Still the attribute may be `undefined` too, so boxing `v` to a number manually makes sense.

Comment: @KooiInc As Kevin pointed, it doesnt require parsing the value. The function reduces the width by 50 and thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Anand: that's only because you are subtracting and the current attribute value can be boxed into a number. If you added a value (`v + 50`) that would result (in this case) in `28450`. You have to take things like that into account when you are programming, especially in javasecript.